# How to get audit log on sharepoint CSOM

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, csom

hi i want to get value of audit log via CSOM.is that posible?not via crawling website for downloading that file.so i can make some API to return audit log value.

when i try to this
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/248948/site-collection-audit-settings-for-sp-online-using-csom

this is i can't get value it's only save to path.

how to get the value of audit log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my knowledge,CSOM could not get audit log.
[image]
https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329220-sharepoint-dev-platform/suggestions/8967484-microsoft-sharepoint-client-auditquery-in-csom

You could only use CSOM to configure Audit log.

Comment: hmmm any idea how to get that audit log via download or anything?